# Adding ips using cloudconfig file in coreos

Tags: cloud, coreos

I am using cloudconfig file to add new ip addresses to the system. But for some reason, it just won't add the ip address. Can someone please help me?

Here is the contents of my cloudconfig file:

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
coreos:
  units:
    - name: update-sysctl.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Update sysctl values written by cloud-config
        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        ExecStart=ip addr add 172.31.118.62 dev eth0:1
        ExecStart=ip addr add 172.31.118.63 dev eth0:2
        ExecStart=ip addr add 172.31.118.64 dev eth0:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was not giving the full command path, so thats why it was not working. The given config below is a working one!

```
#cloud-config
coreos:
  units:
    - name: update-sysctl.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Update sysctl values written by cloud-config
        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        ExecStart=/bin/ip addr add 172.31.118.62 dev eth0:1
        ExecStart=/bin/ip addr add 172.31.118.63 dev eth0:2
        ExecStart=/bin/ip addr add 172.31.118.64 dev eth0:3
```